# Unable to add UICollectionViewCell to UICollectionView by dragging

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

It's my first time trying to work with `UICollectionView`. 
I am trying out this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pvvn1L2aPyA). 
He dragged `UICollectionView`, and then he dragged the `UICollectionViewCell` and dropped it inside the `Collection View`. I have trouble doing it: When I drag the cell to the view, it doesn't stick. Just "flays" back to the controls library. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show some code or try to check: https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout

Comment: I was not in the code, but in the interface builder